# How to animate Label color to make it glow?

Tags: java, animation, colors, swt

I am writing an SWT application.

Is there a way to animate a label to make it glow in SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT uses the OS's widgets. There are methods like [`setForeground()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#getForeground%28%29) and [`setBackground()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#getBackground%28%29). However, it is not guaranteed, that the set colors will be used (they are just hints). In general: There is no built-in mechanism that will make your `Label` glow.

As a workaround, add a `Listener` for `SWT.Paint` to your `Label`. On this `Listener`'s `handleEvent` method, get the `Event`'s `GC` and paint whatever you want with it:

```
label.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        GC gc = event.gc;
        // paint what you want
    }
});
```